# Printing number of items in a range from an array in Kotlin

Tags: arrays, kotlin, range

Currently working on a little school assignment, trying to figure out if there is a specific way to print items out of a randomized array. Teacher wants us to generate 200 random numbers in a range of 1 through 100, store them, and then print them with the amount of each range(10s, 20s, 30s, etc). I've gotten the randomization and storage down, but I'm having a little issue trying to figure out how to properly display these.

We should have them separated by how many random numbers are 1-10, 11-20, etc etc, but also with a histograph to the side. I think I can figure out the histograph well enough, but I could use some help on how to display the numbers for each range! I hope this makes sense, any help is appreciated!

What I have so far is very simple, just having a rough time figuring out what goes in the println()

```
fun main() {
    val rnds = (1..200).map { (1..100).random() }
    println() // <-- ???
}
```

it should look something like:

```
1 - 10:   # // <-- number of randomized numbers in that range here
11 - 20:  # // <-- number of randomized numbers in that range here
21 - 30:  # // <-- number of randomized numbers in that range here
```

etc etc, all the way until 91 - 100

I should also mention that I'm VERY new to kotlin, and still pretty green to programming in general. The easier the solution, the better, at least until I have a better understanding at what I'm seeing.

Comment: Pseudocoding this, you'll need to do a couple things:  First you'll need some bins
`val bins = arrayListOf(0, 10, 20, 30)`
then for each of them you'll want to filter the range
`val counts = bins.map{ low -> rnds.filter{ r -> low < r && r < low + 10}.size()}`

Answer (score 1):

You can create your range buckets by using the `map` function on a range of each starting number of a bucket, and then `associateWith` to sort the original lists into these buckets:

```
val byRanges: Map<IntRange, List<Int>> = (1..100 step 10)
    .map { it..(it + 9) }
    .associateWith { range -> rnds.filter { it in range } }
```

Then when you want to convert this to text, you can use the `joinToString()` function on the map `entries` to format each item as text:

```
val asText: String = byRanges.entries.joinToString("\n") { (range, list) ->
    "${range.start} - ${range.endInclusive}: # ${list.size}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the "for" loop by range value and filter the list with desired condition to get the item count.

```
fun main() {
   val randomRangeStart = 1
   val randomRangeEnd = 100
   val list = (1..200).map { (randomRangeStart..randomRangeEnd).random() }
   for (i in randomRangeStart..randomRangeEnd step 10) {
      println("Range $i - ${i+9}: ${list.filter { it >= i && it <= i+9 }.count()}")
   }
}
```